# Problem solving a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, arithmetic, nonlinear-system

How can I solve this equation system for x and y?

$\frac{xy}{x+1} = a$

$\frac{xy^2}{x+2} = b$

$a>0$  $b>0$

I've tried to isolate $y$ of both equations and then equal the result to solve $x$ but then I can't isolate $x$. I've also tried to combine the two equations but I get nothing.

Comment: Divide the second equation by the first.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
y=\frac{a(x+1)}{x}\ \text{and}\
y^2=\frac{b(x+2)}{x}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{a^2(x+1)^2}{x^2}=\frac{b(x+2)}{x}
$$
that is
$$a^2(x+1)^2=bx(x+2)$$
Hence
$$
(a^2-b)x^2+2(a^2-b)x+a^2=0
$$
Now solve this quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

Square the first equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^2y^2}{(x+1)^2}=a^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now rewrite the second equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^2y^2}{(x+1)^2}  \times\frac{(x+1)^2}{x(x+2)} =b.
\end{eqnarray*}
So we have the quadratic
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^2(x+1)^2=bx(x+2) 
\end{eqnarray*}
which is easily solved.